# Given four points on a cubic function curve, this function?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

[image]

I've gotten the answer y = 0.73095x³ +
    1.17857x² +
    -10.78095x +
    4

Using the steps outlined in an earlier question asking this question, which could be found here: [Given four points on a cubic function curve, how can I find the curve's function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168855/given-four-points-on-a-cubic-function-curve-how-can-i-find-the-curves-function)

This answer is marked as incorrect. Am I missing something"

Comment: Looks correct, I wonder if it wants in an fractional form like $\dfrac{307 x^3}{420}+\dfrac{33 x^2}{28}-\dfrac{1132 x}{105} + 4$?

Comment: Excel agrees with you unless the precision of the numbers is a problem.  This would indicate you are doing the right thing and either the answer checker is wrong or you are using the wrong input format.

Comment: You are omitting "y=" from what you type into the blank, yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Lagrange's formula, we have 
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \frac{(x-2)(x-3)(x+5)}{(0-2)(0-3)(0-5)}f(0) + \frac{(x-0)(x-3)(x+5)}{(2-0)(2-3)(2-5)}f(2) \\
&+ \frac{(x-0)(x-2)(x+5)}{(3-0)(3-2)(3-5)}f(3) +\frac{(x-0)(x-2)(x-3)}{(-5-0)(-5-2)(-5-3)}f(-5) 
\end{align*}